# R split string with RegExp but containing those characters

Tags: regex, r

How can I split the following string?

> "Wes Anderson – The Grand Budapest HotelRichard Linklater – BoyhoodBennett Miller – FoxcatcherMorten Tyldum – The Imitation Game"

into:

```
"Wes Anderson – The Grand Budapest Hotel"
"Richard Linklater – Boyhood"
"Bennett Miller – Foxcatcher"
"Morten Tyldum – The Imitation Game"
```

The first split point is "HotelRichard" so I think a word containing [a-z][A-Z] could be used to find the rules. But if I substitute those part using:

```
strsplit("HotelRichard", "[a-z][A-Z]") returns "Hote" "ichard".
```

Any good ideas for that?

Comment: How did you wind up with such a string? Are you sure there isn't a way to prevent the strings from being smooshed in the first place?

Comment: Those are separated by <br> tag so if I get it by "xmlValue" in XML library, it just returns that way. I tried to switch <br> in the original html, but it didn't work.

Comment: Well then use an XML selector to select the text() nodes and grab those xmlValues instead. For example with `xx<-xmlParse("<a><b>One<br/>Two<br/>Three</b></a>")`, use `xpathSApply(xx, "//b/text()", xmlValue)` rather than `xpathSApply(xx, "//b", xmlValue)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using this code where I am using a kind of a workaround to insert a `§` sign (hopefully, it is not that frequent if at all in your input) and then split by it:

```
x <- "Wes Anderson – The Grand Budapest HotelRichard Linklater – BoyhoodBennett Miller – FoxcatcherMorten Tyldum – The Imitation Game"
x <- gsub("([a-z])([A-Z])","\\1§\\2",x)
strsplit(x,"§")
```

[Sample program](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_r_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMUTRCTVhlTnF4ZEE) output:

```
[[1]]                                                                                                                                                               
[1] "Wes Anderson \342\200\223 The Grand Budapest Hotel"                                                                                                            
[2] "Richard Linklater \342\200\223 Boyhood"                                                                                                                        
[3] "Bennett Miller \342\200\223 Foxcatcher"                                                                                                                        
[4] "Morten Tyldum \342\200\223 The Imitation Game"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response. For example, in this case, "Steve McQueen – 12 Years a SlaveAlexander Payne – NebraskaDavid O. Russell – American Hustleartin Scorsese – The Wolf of Wall Street" "McQueen" is also splitted to "Mc and "Queen". I tried to include something like this "(.*)( – )(.*)([a-z])([A-Z])" but doesn't work. Any additional RegEx in this case? Thanks!!

Comment: It is clear you cannot be 100% sure in such cases. A quick and dirty solution is to exclude these 'cQ' cases with `([abd-z])([A-PR-Z])` regex. Maybe there will be no cases when a string ends in `c` and next line starts with `Q`.

Comment: Thanks! but there are more cases like this, so I'm looking for a more general solution.

Comment: The solution is only one: get the contents with <br> tags. I know this pain as I have been in the localization industry for years.

Answer (score 0):

First break apart the director/film mashups, then split the string at the inserted "xxx".  The first steps marks two groups and then replaces them with the three x's in between.

```
text <- "Wes Anderson – The Grand Budapest HotelRichard Linklater – BoyhoodBennett Miller – FoxcatcherMorten Tyldum – The Imitation Game"
text.split <- str_replace_all(text, "([a-z])([A-Z])", "\\1xxx\\2")
text.final <- str_split(text.split, "xxx")
text.final
[[1]]
[1] "Wes Anderson – The Grand Budapest Hotel" "Richard Linklater – Boyhood"            
[3] "Bennett Miller – Foxcatcher"             "Morten Tyldum – The Imitation Game"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach using a single regex (a Lookahead and Lookbehind):

```
strsplit(x, "(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])", perl = TRUE)

## [[1]]
## [1] "Wes Anderson – The Grand Budapest Hotel"
## [2] "Richard Linklater – Boyhood"            
## [3] "Bennett Miller – Foxcatcher"            
## [4] "Morten Tyldum – The Imitation Game"
```